# What happened to the Heroes from Diablo 1?

Tags: video-games, diablo

<sup>Inspired by: [Who were the heroes in Diablo?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15729/3804)</sup>

We see at the end of the Diablo I game the Hero shoves the soulstone into his head, hoping to contain Diablo himself, and stop him from corrupting any others. Becoming the dark wanderer from the cinematics of Diablo II

Whilst there is an animation showing all of the Heroes shoving the soulstone into their heads, are there any hints of clues as to what happened to the other heroes, the ones who didn't face Diablo?

Comment: Why did you ask yourself a question?

Comment: I was going to post my answer to the [Who were the heroes in Diablo?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15729/3804) question but when I realised it wasn't answering the question and it contained interesting information I decided it was worth posting the question and answers together for the benefit of stackexchange. [It's ok you answer your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: I'm fairly sure this exact question was asked and answered on gaming.  Does it belong on both sites?

Comment: @C.Ross That's a good question.

Comment: @Pureferret [Who is the hero that “uses” the soulstone at the end of Diablo?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/64648/121)

Comment: @C.Ross the question is, the answers there are unsubstantiated from the game alone. It needs the confirmation from the Book of Cain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we don't consider cross sites when counting duplicate questions. It seems unreasonable to search through all SE sites before asking a question. I'll ask on meta, though.

Comment: @Pureferret, I hear ya. I hate when I type up a bunch uf stuff and then decide it doesn't really fit the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are hints that the Rogue is the Blood Raven:

> *"My Rogue scouts have just reported an abomination in the Monastery graveyard! **Apparently, Andariel is not content to take only our living.
> Blood Raven,** one of our finest captains in the battle against Diablo at Tristram, was also one of the first to be corrupted by Andariel. Now, you'll find her in the Monastery graveyard raising our dead as zombies!
> We cannot abide this defilement! If you are truly our ally, you will help us destroy her."*

#### ~Kaysha giving the Bloodraven quest.

And that the summoner you face is the Sorcerer from Diablo 1, as hinted at by Drognan:

> *"Not long ago, one of my Vizjerei comrades, **who I believed had died in Tristram,** came to this city. He seemed quite insane, so I dismissed much of what he said. However, he was able to talk his way into Jerhyn's palace. No one has seen him since. I fear that fool may have found something in the palace that led to his doom."*

And later on giving you the quest:

> *"Yes... The man you speak of sounds like the mage who came here many months ago. **He claimed to have fought Diablo in the passages beneath Tristram.** No doubt the fool wandered into Horazon's Sanctuary and lost whatever was left of his ravaged mind. He is beyond salvation. It is possible that the fool has been possessed by the spirit of Horazon. If that's true, then you'd better put an end to his tortured existence. Once done, I believe the demons who were summoned and imprisoned within the Sanctuary will cease to exist as well."*

#### ~Drognan giving the Summoner Quest.

So it appears in the games canon, all three heroes fought Diablo, with only one becoming the Dark Wanderer. The others went their own way, The Rogue rejoining the Sisters of the Sightless Eye, becoming the corrupted Blood Raven eventually, and The Sorcerer travelling to Lut Gholein, to become the Summoner.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer provided by [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15976/46407), the backstory was retconned into Diablo 2; since there was very little provided in the first game. However, there were a few small hints (that Blizzard used to tie the story created in Diablo 2) that can be found in Diablo 1.

Firstly, King Leoric, and his son Albrecht were the first victims of Diablo. When you receive the "Curse of King Leoric" quest from [Ogden](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Ogden_the_Tavern_Owner), he reveals the link between Leoric's family and Diablo.

> The village needs your help, good master! Some months ago King Leoric's son, Prince Albrecht, was kidnapped. The King went into a rage and scoured the village for his missing child. With each passing day, Leoric seemed to slip deeper into madness. He sought to blame innocent townsfolk for the boy's disappearance and had them brutally executed. Less than half of us survived his insanity...The King's Knights and Priests tried to placate him, but he turned against them and sadly, they were forced to kill him. With his dying breath the King called down a terrible curse upon his former followers. He vowed that they would serve him in darkness forever...This is where things take an even darker twist than I thought possible! Our former King has risen from his eternal sleep and now commands a legion of undead minions within the Labyrinth. His body was buried in a tomb three levels beneath the Cathedral. Please, good master, put his soul at ease by destroying his now cursed form...

Additionally, Ogden's greeting implies that the hero has "returned".

> Thank goodness you've returned! Much has changed since you lived here, my friend.

<sup>I *believe* this was only for the Warrior, implying that he was the only one of the three that came from Tristram, but I can't find any citation for it at this time</sup>

The only other link we might be able to identify is that, while you never see the character's face (it is silhouetted in the animation) we have 2 clues:

1. The voice (when they scream after shoving the Soulstone into their head) is male
2. The armour looks like the [Warrior's late game armour](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Warrior?file=Warrior2.gif).

So, this gives us a link between the Warrior, and the [Dark Wanderer/Aidan](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Aidan) within the context of the first game.

That leaves the other two; the Rogue, and the Sorcerer. Unfortunately, there is no link to these two within the context of the first game. But, as the previous answer provides, they were addressed in Diablo 2. The lore also expands on this, adding more detail about the characters themselves.

[Moreina](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Blood_Raven) was the Rogue from Diablo 1.

> Blood Raven is the canonical depiction of the Rogue class in Diablo I, though remains unnamed in said game.

The lore expands on her situation, following the events of Diablo 1. The evil within the Cathedral was more powerful than anyone expected, being powerful enough to corrupt any who ventured long, and deep enough into the dungeon.

> After Diablo's defeat, Moreina returned to her order. However, she carried something dark within her; a silent madness that ate away at her once noble heart. […] taking on the name of "Blood Raven," Moreina fell into league with Andariel as the Lesser Evil took over Eastgate Keep. Blood Raven assaulted her fellow Rogues in the battle,[1](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Ogden_the_Tavern_Owner) and at some point, was made undead.

[Jazreth](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/The_Summoner) is managed similarly in the linkage between the games.

> The Summoner is the sorcerer character of the first game, though remains unnamed in said game. The confirmation of the two being the same character came much later.

Similar to Moreina, Jazreth was also affected by his delving into the Cathedral depths, but instead of being corrupted by the evils, it instead drove him mad; he hunted for knowledge, and power.

> Scarred by his experiences, Jazreth traveled to Lut Gholein to find the mystical Arcane Sanctuary of the great mage Horazon. He met Drognan, an old comrade of his, and told him of his fight against Diablo, but such were his ramblings that the man dismissed much of what he had said. […] Drognan would later speculate that the Summoner had possibly been possessed by the spirit of Horazon.
>
> The Summoner believed that he could bend evil forces to his will. What he didn’t know was that evil uses man, not the reverse.